# kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init ! on centos running on my embedded board

Tags: centos, libc

I am currently working on centos running on intel atom board. I mistakenly renamed lic-2.17.so to _libc-2.17.so
     library on my board, when I reboot the board it is giving me below error.

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Initrd Default Target.
systemd-journald[136]: Received SIGTERM
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Is there any possible way to get back to the original state.
I entered into grub prompt and able to see cat /lib64/_libc-2.17.so. Not Sure,
how to rename this to original name

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you enter run-level 3 from grub?

if so,

```
sudo mv /lib64/_libc-2.17.so /lib64/libc-2.17.so
```

if you can't enter run-level 3, you can try using a live DVD/USB to run the above command, you're just going to have to manually search for the right partition which the incorrectly named file is located.

Otherwise, I'm afraid you're going to need to reinstall the OS.

Comment: run-level 3 is not working, there is no other option other than installing new os ?

Comment: did you try the live disc?

Comment: Since i am using embedded board, which centos iso i can use (minimal ISO/DVD ISO

Comment: You should be able to use any of them. I would go for the minimal ISO.
    [link](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01.iso)

Comment: Hi S3v3nL34fKl0v3r , getting 3 options Install centos7 , Test this media and install centos7, Trouble shooting. I dont want to install on my board. I want to use it from usb.

Comment: First I would like to apologize, I had forgotten how the CentOS live DVD works. You're going to want to install CentOS to a USB, and boot from that USB. You should be able to do this easily enough, however, it defeats the purpose of you not wanting to reinstall the OS. I am curious though, why CentOS?

Comment: Any Linux Based OS is fine. Done installed centos. Conclusion, never play with libc :)

Comment: Yeah... renaming library files can be tricky... especially libc :)

Comment: @anikhan you will have to mount your removable drive, and install from disk to that drive. I have no idea how long this can take, as we have USB 1-3, and what your computer is capable of.